# transparent plots flash white when updating

Tags: dynamic, display

As my university moves to online instruction, I am trying to make high-quality video presentations using Mathematica slide shows.  I can easily get the content I want, but it seems tricky to display it over anything but a white background, which is quite the eyesore.  Static content works well, but when I try to update dynamically I get flashes of white background.

For example, here is code for a notebook on Fourier series.  To replicate the effect, use in a slideshow notebook with a background image set.  (If you want it to look exactly the same as mine, use the title slide background image from the "Earth" theme.)

```
color2 = ColorData[10, "ColorList"][[3]];
nterms[NN_] := 
 1/2 + 2/\[Pi] Sum[1/(2 n - 1) Sin[(2 n - 1) x], {n, 1, NN - 1}]
nicePlot[NN_] := 
 Plot[{Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {1, x > 0}}], 
   nterms[NN]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Thickness[.01], Gray}], 
    Directive[Thickness[.005], color2]}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[Style[ToString[NN] <> " terms", color2, 30, 
     Italic], {.9, .9}], 
  Ticks -> {{-\[Pi], -\[Pi]/2, 0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]}, {-1/2, 0, 1/2, 1, 
     3/2}}, TicksStyle -> Directive[14], 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[.002]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {-.5, 1.5}}]
```

Then I pre-make plots so they display quickly

```
frames = Table[Show[nicePlot[nn], ImageSize -> 700], {nn, 1, 50, 1}];
```

If I just look at a frame in slideshow mode, it correctly displays with a transparent background color, so I can see the background image:

[image]

However, if I try a manipulate, the transparency doesn't go through and the plots look white.  So instead I did a dynamic module:

```
n = 1;
DynamicModule[
  {u = frames[[n]]},
  EventHandler[
    Dynamic@u,
    {
      {"MouseClicked", 2} :> (u = frames[[++n]]), 
       {"MouseClicked", 1} :> (u = frames[[--n]])
      }
    ]
  ]
```

This works except that when I click to change it, it quickly flashes white before going transparent.  Actually it doesn't do it every single time, so it must be a pretty low-level issue.  Does anybody know how to fix this?  If Mathematica can't dynamically update without visual glitches, it's going to be a showstopper in terms of using the platform to create quality content.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try manually setting a `Background->None` on the `Plot`. Can't promise it'll work but it might.

Comment: ```Manipulate[frames[[k]], {k, 1, Length@frames, 1}, Paneled -> False]``` makes transparent manipulates, but flashing effect still exists.

Comment: ```Background->None``` doesn't help unfortunately.  Thanks for the manipulate syntax.  I guess since two methods produce the same glitch for at least two users, this should be considered a bug?

Comment: wolfram support confirmed it appears to be a bug and reported it internally.  solid-color backgrounds (e.g. Opal template non-title slide) work fine, so I'll use that for the time being.  Will update if wolfram fixes.